# External disk mount again after safe removal

Tags: mount, disk

I have an external `ntfs` disk. When I try to safe remove it, after few seconds it is mounted again without doing nothing... This happens every time and with every remove method I tried:

- clicking on "safe remove" on `nautilus`
- clicking first "umount" and then "safe remove" on `nautilus`
- from terminal using `sudo udisks --unmount` followed by `sudo udisks --detach`

How can I safe remove the disk?

If I disconnect the disk after unmounting it but without safe removal (the light on the disk is still on) the disk can be damaged?

Comment: Looks like a faulty cable or port.  Do you have another cable/port you can use?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a Nautilus, or some other program, window open and with the current directory of that drive?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem with some large USB drives as well.  I use Nautilus to "Safely Remove."  A few seconds later, it mounts itself again.  I use Nautilus again to "safely Remove."  After the 2nd time, it powers down and stays powered down.